# Prove ¬(¬a = a)

Tags: logic, proof

This looks like such an easy problem but still can't figure it out. How do I prove ¬(¬a = a)?

No given premises.

I got this so far (in Fitch):

[image: proof so far]

This is a subproof where I assume the negation of my goal and then try to reach the absurd/contradiction so I can state the negation of my assumption, which would be my goal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should I interpret that as ¬(¬(*a* = *a*)) ? Because it seems like "=" denotes equality (and not "if and only if"), and if "=" denotes equality, then *a* must be an element which means that ¬*a* is not a valid formula.

Comment: No, you should interpret it as ¬(¬a = a) which is a perfectly valid sentence. ¬a = a is just a false sentence and the negation would make it true.

Comment: So *a* is a predicate? (Note that [the screenshot you posted](http://gyazo.com/feab1b469ffe2a9b9a90267db620f9f0) seems to agree with me as it says *"This formula is not well formed"*)

Comment: I've explained my view of this in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhU9l.png) I'd say your *=Intro* introduces a variable *a* (that is, *a* is an object of the domain, rather than a predicate).

I say this because

1. in all books I've read, the *=Intro* rule is used for objects rather than predicates, and
2. for predicates, equals is expressed as *"if and only if"* which is typically written as ↔ and not =.

So, in other words, the only sensible interpretation of ¬(¬a = a) is that = binds harder than ¬, and the whole formula should be interpreted as ¬(¬(a = a)).

Now you should be able to

1. introduce a = a
2. assume the contrary: ¬(a = a)
3. arrive at a contradiction, ⊥, based on 1. and 2.
4. Use ¬Intro on 2 and 3 to get ¬(¬(a = a)).

Comment: Thanks, this works. http://gyazo.com/81218fb304d7848a42349cc459428010. But, it's still very confusing. Why does ¬ have higher precedence than =? Intuitively this makes no sense to me. Sorry, it's just my second week of studying Logic.

Comment: You nailed it :-) No problem. I know it can be confusing. (I've been a teaching assistant in a CS logics course)

Comment: You can ping me on email if you post more logics related questions.

Comment: Thanks aioobe, I posted another Logic question. Would be great if you could take a look at it! (can't find your email)